# how to add content type from front end in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-content-types

**I am new to Drupal and the problem is described below:**

I have created content type "exercise" and what i want is to add this content type from front end like http://domain.com/add-exercise. Please let us know in details what steps will be needed to attempt this.

**
I have users who will add exercises, so i dont want them to add these by using backend i just want to let them add by frontend like http://domain.com/add-exercise 
**

Please elaborate in detail because i am totally new to drupal.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First of all, *there is not really a "frontend" and "backend" notion* in Drupal. You can just see the administration interface through the **admin theme** or the through the **main theme**.

If you want the users access the "add exercice" node form through the main theme, just go to `admin>people>permissions`, and under `system` **uncheck the permission** "`access the administration theme`" in the column of the role you want (e.g: authenticated users).

Don't forget to set the "exercice: add new content" as checked in their permissions as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check below URL is working for me as a same issue face last.

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/96016/content-type-turn-in-to-form-on-front-end-to-be-used